# Integration - indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2+4x}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$
\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2+4x}} dx
$$

I have tried different substitutions writing the denominator as $x \sqrt{(x+2)^2-4}$ but can't make it work.

Comment: You can try $u=x+2$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, $x>0$, write the integrand as
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4/x}}\frac{1}{x^2},
$$
and let $t=1/x$. You get
$$
-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4t}}\,dt,
$$
which I'm sure you can handle. Also, once you are done, try to think about the case of negative $x$.

Comment: Thanks so much - I was on the wrong track.